# R -- doesn't delimit input columns correctly when some charracters (e.g. #) appear in the input

Tags: r, input, csv

My input file is simple tab-delimited data with **3** columns

cat input

```
1\thello dolly\t1
2\t#hi\t2
```

A part of R script:

```
...
input<-read.table(IN,header=FALSE,sep="\t",quote="",nrows=1,fileEncoding="UTF-8")
message(i,":line; col=", ncol(row));
...
```

When the input file is processed by the R script, I got *error in  2. line*:

```
1.line; col=3
2.line; col=2
```

However, when '**#**' is removed from the input I got *correct* result:

```
1.line; col=3
2.line; col=3
```

Why # character influence number of columns - isn't it a bug? Other programs, like awk, always gave the correct number of columns

Comment: You should probably read the documentation before assuming something is a bug. See the `comment.char` argument to `read.table`.

Comment: Thanks @joran - you are right (upvoted). Having '#' set as a default for comments is pretty strange (at least for me). Reading overall documentation for each command in each programming language you use would kill efficiency completely - don't you think?

Comment: On the subject of `comment.char` and `read.table` it's also worth knowing that using `comment.char=""`, as well as fixing your problem, should make the `read.table` complete faster (see `?read.table`), so it's a useful argument to add if you're using a large file that doesn't contain comments.

Comment: I agree that that may be a questionable default. However, it is also _very_ old, in a function that is about as ubiquitous as they get. So changing it would break lots and lots and lots of stuff. Also, note the existence of specific `read.csv` and `read.delim` functions that use sensible defaults for specific file types. If you choose to use the most general function, it's up to you to read the docs! :)